# IAP Apple hosted content download progress issue

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, skdownload

---

Hi All. I have an app with IAP Apple hosted content. The SKDownload.progress works well, proceeding in 1% increments, up until about 0.8, after which my updatedDownloads: method stops getting called. Then after 3-5 minutes I get a SKDownloadStateFinished and everything is OK. Has anyone got any tips on this or is it perhaps an Apple bug? The app was rejected with message "he download stalls at 80% after completing the In App Purchase".